# Error in loading google Ads: com.google.admob Code=8 Swift ios

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, google-ads-script

Can someone help me with this Error?:

> Error Domain=com.google.admob Code=8 "Cannot find an ad network
> adapter with the name(s): com.google.DummyAdapter. Remember to link
> all required ad network adapters and SDKs, and set -ObjC in the 'Other
> Linker Flags' setting of your build target."
> UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Cannot find an ad network adapter
> with the name(s): com.google.DummyAdapter. Remember to link all
> required ad network adapters and SDKs, and set -ObjC in the 'Other
> Linker Flags' setting of your build target.}

Comment: did you got same issue on real device or working on simulator?